# React.js map function is overwriting new items in an array instead of adding them

Tags: reactjs, arrays

I have a React app that has a parent component , and two child components:  and .

The  component has a form for user input that defines parameters sent in a REST API call defined in a makeCall() function.

declares an array called "records" and a method "setRecords", both of which are passed to  as props. The makeCall() function makes the call, processes the response, and uses "setRecords" to add the response as a new item in "records". The  component uses map() on "records" to create  components for each item in "records".

**Relevant bits of App.tsx**

```
...
const [records, setRecords] = React.useState<Array<RecordsList>>([]); 
...  
return (
    <Request
      setRecords={setRecords}
      records={records}
    />
    {records.map(record => (
       <Response
         key={record.key}
         showModel={record.response}
       />
     ))}
  )
```

This is part of the  component code. Again, "records" and "setRecords" are passed to the component as props, their type is set in an interface called "RequestProps". A button event triggers makeCall().

**Relevant bits of Request.tsx**

```
export default function Request(props: RequestProps) {
    const makeCall = async (inputText: string, option: string) => {
    await fetch(url, { 
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(inputText)
      })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      props.setRecords([ // adds the response to records
        {
          key: props.key 
          response: data.body
        },
        ...props.records
      ]);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

I tried to update the  component so that if a user selects multiple options on the form, a function will make a separate API call for each option using makeCall().

I am using map() within the button event handler in  to loop over the selected options:

```
async function handleSubmit(event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
    event.preventDefault();
    await Promise.all(selectedOptions.map(async option => {  
      return await makeCall(inputText, option.value)
    }));

  }
```

For some reason, subsequent "setRecords" overwrite the previous record item so that only the last item ends up in "records".

I'm new to React and a not sure what I'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
props.setRecords([
  {
    key: props.key 
    response: data.body
  },
  ...props.records
]);
```

Is specifically using the existing `records` that was passed as a prop.  So if you invoke `makeCull` multiple times in parallel, each one of those calls is using the *same* instance of `records` from the same props.  So each one is adding a single record to whatever `records` was at that time.

Instead, you want each of these parallel operations to update the state *as it currently exists*, not as it existed when it was passed to the component.  That way ongoing changes to state can be preserved.

To access that "current" state value regardless of what updates have been made already, use the callback version of the state setter which provides that value as its function argument:

```
props.setRecords(prev => ([
  {
    key: props.key 
    response: data.body
  },
  ...prev
]));
```